# creating Javascript animations within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am making a small animation withing a HTML file that is mainly handled by  embedded JavaScript, my oly problem is that the code below does not seem to work due to some logic error or a misuse of a function (still not entirely sure where).
Could someone offer an alternitive or a fix?

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <head>
      <script>
        function onload(){
          while (1!=1){
            console.log("True")
            function SI(){
              console.log("SI")
              var greenOn = document.getElementById("green").style.display;
              var yellowOn = document.getElementById("yellow").style.display;
              var redOn = document.getElementById("red").style.display;
              if (greenOn != "none"){
                document.getElementById("green").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "";
              }
              else if (yellowOn != "none") {
                document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("red").style.display = "";
              }
              else{
                document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("green").style.display = "";
              }
          }
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("Color change")},3000);
        SI();
      }
    }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img id="red" src="red.png" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
      <img id="yellow" src="yellow.png" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
      <img id="green" src="Green.jpg" style="display: ;" width="400" height="400"/>
      <br/>
      <p onload="onload()"></p>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in your browser console?  "It doesn't work" is an insufficient description of the problem.

Comment: nope, no errors. i am using IE because of a project requirement

Comment: Where are you calling the function `SI`?

Comment: *facepalm*. I've made some improvements now, ill update the page, same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the function doesn't really make sense. I am not sure what the `while(true)` is susposed to do? From review it appears it keeps defining the function `SI()`. Now also your timeout `setTimeout(function(){console.log("Color change")},3000);` all that will do is 3 seconds after the `onload` fires will write `Color Change` to the console.

Now what I believe you want is that every `3000`ms (3 seconds) you wish to toggle change the images `display` property.

First start with moving the `SI()` method outside of the the `onload` function. This is not required but will make it slightly easier to understand (also recommend changing the function name to be more descriptive).

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
      SI();
    }, 3000);

}
function SI() {
    console.log('Color change');
  var greenOn = document.getElementById("green").style.display;
  var yellowOn = document.getElementById("yellow").style.display;
  var redOn = document.getElementById("red").style.display;
  if (greenOn != "none") {
    document.getElementById("green").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "";
  } else if (yellowOn != "none") {
    document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("green").style.display = "";
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
      SI();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Now you will see I have changed things a bit. First I removed the `onload()` function and instead used the `window.onload` method attaching a function to run when the window loads.

This starts the `3000`ms timer to run the function `SI()`. Where at the end of the `SI()` function sets another timeout to run the function `SI()` after `3000`ms

**EDIT FOR FUN**

Just for fun created a CSS only version.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    changeCircleColor();
  }, 3000);

});

function changeClass(e, from, to) {
  e.removeClass(from).addClass(to);
}

function changeCircleColor() {
  
  var c = $('#circle');
  if (c.hasClass('red')) changeClass(c, 'red', 'green');
  else if (c.hasClass('yellow')) changeClass(c, 'yellow', 'red');
  else changeClass(c, 'green', 'yellow')

  setTimeout(function() {
    changeCircleColor();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.circle.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.circle.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.circle.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="circle" class="circle red"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <head>
      <script>
        function onload(){
            var greenOn = document.getElementById("green").style.display;
            var yellowOn = document.getElementById("yellow").style.display;
            var redOn = document.getElementById("red").style.display;
            if (greenOn != "none"){
              document.getElementById("green").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "";
            }
            else if (yellowOn != "none") {
              document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("red").style.display = "";
            }
            else{
              document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("green").style.display = "";
            }
    console.log("Color change");
        setTimeout(function(){onload()},3000);
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <img id="red" src="red.png" alt="Red" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
      <img id="yellow" src="yellow.png" alt="Yellow" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
      <img id="green" src="Green.jpg" alt="Green" style="display: ;" width="400" height="400"/>

  <script>
  onload()
  </script>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Also, please note that there are definitely better approaches to this, but this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the set interval must be an external function. One solution can be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <HTML>
      <head>
  <script>

              function SI(){
                var greenOn = document.getElementById("green").style.display;
                var yellowOn = document.getElementById("yellow").style.display;
                var redOn = document.getElementById("red").style.display;
                if (greenOn != "none"){
                  document.getElementById("green").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "";
                }
                else if (yellowOn != "none") {
                  document.getElementById("yellow").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("red").style.display = "";
                }
                else{
                  document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("green").style.display = "";
                }
              }

                function Timer(){
              setTimeout(SI(),3000);
    }
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <img id="red" src="red.png" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
          <img id="yellow" src="yellow.png" style="display: none;" width="400" height="400"/>
          <img id="green" src="Green.jpg" style="display: ;" width="400" height="400"/>
          <br/>
          <p onload="Timer()" />
      </body>
    </HTML>
```